# Calculate Sum of a Field, say, Bill_Amount for a particular Customer_Name from a table/RecordType in CloudKit and Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have a Sales table in Cloudkit which has Customer_Name and Bill_Amount as separate fields. How can I calculate the sum of all customers' Bill_Amount values and show it in a UITableView, like this?

```
    Sales from Customer
    ------------------------------------
    Customer_Name            Sales Amount
    ------------------------------------                        
    Customer A.               50,000                          
    Customer B.               30,000                
    Customer C.               60,000            
    Customer D.               50,000
```

In CloudKit I have two tables: a) Transactions b) PartyAccounts. PartyAccounts contains all party Details. Transactions contains Txn_ID, Txn_Date, Party, Amount, Remarks.

I want to show Summary in UITableView like above that until now which party have what Balance. I have tried many things like adding two different arrays, [String] for for party Names and [Double] for PartyBalances, and all data loads up when I click the viewAllTapped button tapped for UITableView Reloads, not on viewLoad event.

My code is:

```
//
//  ViewController4.swift
//  General Ledger
//
//  Created by Aakash Vijay on 21/07/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Aakash Vijay. All rights reserved.
//

    import UIKit
    import CloudKit
    import MobileCoreServices

    class ViewController4: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        var loadTransactionData = [CKRecord]()
        var partyAccountsData = [CKRecord]()
        let publicDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        let cntr = CKContainer.default()
        typealias finshedFunction = () -> ()
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
        var partyNames : [String] = []
        var partyBalances : [Double] = []


        //viewAllTapped is Button That Reloads UITableView
        @IBAction func viewAllTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {        
            print(self.partyAccountsData.count)
            print(self.loadTransactionData.count)
            print(partyBalances.count)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        var ptyAmt : Double = 0.0
        var ptyNam : String = ""
        var tmpPty : String = ""


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            view1.layer.borderWidth = 1
            view1.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1
            tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            self.loadNewData()    /// Data Loaded(But Now Shown in TableView) i Don't know Why Sometimes executes full code and sometimes shows error.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.partyAccountsData.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewPartyBalanceTVC
            cell.view2.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.view2.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.nameLabel.text = String(self.partyAccountsData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "Party_Name") as! String)
            cell.amountLabel.text = String(self.partyBalances[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
    /// Now partyAccountsData refers to all party
//////// loadNewData fills partyAccountsData with PartyAccounts Table's Data
        func loadNewData() {
            let qry = CKQuery(recordType: "PartyAccounts", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
            qry.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Party_ID", ascending: true)]
            publicDB.perform(qry, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let rcds = results {
                        self.partyAccountsData = rcds
                        //self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                if error != nil {
                    self.showAlert(msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                }
            }

            let qry2 = CKQuery(recordType: "Transactions", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
            qry2.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Party", ascending: true)]
            publicDB.perform(qry2, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) in
           ///// following code adds partyBalance ptyAmt to an array
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let rcds = results {
                        self.ptyAmt = 0
                        for i in 0..<self.partyAccountsData.count {
                            var str1 : String = ""
                            var str2 : String = ""
                            for z in 0..<rcds.count {
                                str1 = self.partyAccountsData[i].value(forKey: "Party_Name") as! String
                                str2 = rcds[z].value(forKey: "Party") as! String
                                if str1 == str2 {
                                    self.ptyAmt = self.ptyAmt + Double(rcds[i].value(forKey: "Amount") as! Double)
                                }
                            }
                            self.partyBalances.append(self.ptyAmt)
                            self.ptyAmt = 0
                        }
                        self.loadTransactionData = rcds
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                    if error != nil {
                        self.showAlert(msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    /////// Code to show Alert
        func showAlert(msg: String)
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "CloudKit", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okButton)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        var tData = [CKRecord]()

        func allDataFill() {
            let qry = CKQuery(recordType: "PartyLedger", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
            qry.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Party_Name", ascending: true)]
            publicDB.perform(qry, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let rcds = results {
                        self.tData = rcds
                    }
                }
                if error != nil {
                    self.showAlert(msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: [Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a detailed description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *does not work*, *please help me* are not acceptable.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking."*

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: I did not write code does not means i did not make efforts. I am trying to solve that from last 3 days and practically solve it too but the result is not shown in tableview in viewLoad event. I will put my code in few mins here.

Comment: @halfer added what i want to do and what i tried in last 3 days.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I can't Understand why you guys think i want my work done by you guys. It's not. I have done what i want but no result because of i m new to Swift code. Swift compiles next line of code before function to complete and this is the main problem i m facing quite often and till now i am not getting solution for that too. My this problem is more often occuring because of that. And that's i want help.

Comment: @Aakash The first version of your question where you did not show your effort was absolutely asking for others to do your work. Maybe this was not your intention but that's what happened. If you don't show your effort we cannot know that you tried something...

Comment: Much better, Aakash. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got an solution for this. i did same as previously but use completion handler and it works perfectly.